# How to use Datatables with Symfony 4 and Webpack Encore?

Tags: jquery, webpack, datatables, symfony4, webpack-encore

I am trying to use Datatables in a Symfony 4 project, using Webpack Encore, I've read [the datatables documentation about integration with yarn](https://datatables.net/download/), lots of tutorials and questions on SO, but I still can't figure how to make it work... I tried all possible configurations and I got errors, or just nothing happens. I ended with:

**Package versions (package.json):**

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.20",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.2.1"
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

I disabled AMD loader (see the last lines):

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    // FEATURE CONFIG
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()
    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

var config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
//disable amd loader
config.module.rules.unshift({
    parser: {
        amd: false,
    }
});
module.exports = config;
```

**app.js**

```js
require('../css/app.scss');
// JQuery and Bootstrap
const $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
// Datatables and datatables-BS4
require('datatables.net-bs4')();
$.fn.dataTable = $.fn.DataTable = global.DataTable = require('datatables.net-bs4');

// Should probably be in the template...
$(document).ready(function() {
     console.log('Applying DT');
     $('#tabletest').DataTable();
});
```

**Test template file:**

```html
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <table id="tabletest">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Having disabled the AMD loader in webpack, and added the line `$.fn.dataTable = $.fn.DataTable = global.DataTable = require('datatables.net-bs4');` in app.js, I have no javascript errors, but datatables is not applied to the `#tabletest` table...

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to import js and css datatables directly from node_modules using 'import' on your app.js?

Comment: @Albeis yes, I tried this at some point, without success.

Comment: Does your table have a `thead` and `tbody` tag ?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber Yes, it has the `thead` end `tbody` tag, I updated my answer to show the whole table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using datatables-bs4 the same way, the only difference is in `app.js`, the way I require it and jQuery, and it's working fine:

```
// require jQuery normally
import $ from 'jquery';
// create global $ and jQuery variables
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

import 'bootstrap' ;

require('datatables.net-bs4')( window, $ );

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTable").DataTable(
        // options
    );
});
```

Comment: Almost... Your solution didn't work for me as if, but I changed `require( 'datatables.net-bs4' );` to `require('datatables.net-bs4')( window, $ );`, and it worked. Please update your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

change `const $ = require('jquery');` to `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

I had the same issue, because window.jQuery was not defined - with the changes above it should work correctly.

**app.js**

```
require('../css/app.scss');

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); //changed
require('bootstrap');
require('datatables.net-bs4');
//removed $.fn.dataTable - not required

$(document).ready(function() {
     console.log('Applying DT');
     $('#tabletest').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: As for the other answer, it was almost working... with `require('datatables.net-bs4')( window, $ );` instead of `require('datatables.net-bs4');`, it was ok. I accepted the other answer because it was the first one, but thanks!